# How to join two tables on two columns normally, but if one of columns contain null, then result must contain rows that match another column only?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One table is item's list, second if something like filter. Columns on filter table can contain null's. It's declared like this:

```
declare @item table(x int, y int);
declare @filter table(x int null, y int null);

insert into @item
values
(1, 1), (1, 5),
(2, 4), (2, 1), (2, 5),
(3, 5);

insert into @filter
values
(1, 1),
(1, null),
(2, 1),
(null, 5);
```

They must be joined on x and y columns. Result should contain only columns from Item table that have columns with same key's in Filter table. But.. If any key-column in Filter table have null as value, then result should include all rows from Items table that match second key-column.

I mean:

```
select item.* 
from @item as item 
left join @filter as filter 
    on (item.x = filter.x and item.y = filter.y)
    /* Something must be here, or join must be written somehow else */

-- Current result:
----------
-- x    y
----------
-- 1    1
-- 2    1

-- Should be:
-------------
-- x    y
-------------
-- 1    1
-- 1    5
-- 2    1
-- 2    5
-- 3    5
```

How to join this tables in such manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this....

```
select Distinct item.* 
from @item as item 
inner join @filter as filter 
    on (item.x = Coalesce(filter.x,item.x) and item.y = Coalesce(filter.y,item.y))
```

[**Sql Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb972/4)

Comment: There might be need to add distinct (some results repeat because of 2+ matching filters)

Comment: Oh.. i didn't thinked about this way.. Added grouping to eliminate duplicates, and now it's works like i need. Thanks!

Comment: @PiotrAuguscik added distinct as u suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to use `CASE` espression in your join `ON` clause like below

```
select item.* 
from @item as item 
left join @filter as filter 
    on item.x = CASE
                    WHEN filter.x IS NULL THEN filter.y ELSE filter.x
                END
    and item.y = CASE
                    WHEN filter.y IS NULL THEN filter.x ELSE filter.y
                 END
```